# cryptography.exceptions.AlreadyFinalized: Context was already finalized

Tags: python, cryptography

I have a binary file which contains some multiple lined data where each line is encrypted before it is written. Now I am trying to read one line at a time and then decrypt it under a loop, but I'm getting and error saying

> cryptography.exceptions.AlreadyFinalized: Context was already finalized.

My sample code it given below:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

key =  #32 bit long key
iv = #16 bit long
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key),modes.CBC(iv),backend = default_backend())
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
database = open("entry.txt",'rb')
for line in database:
    line = line.split(b"  ")
    line = line[0]
    line = (decryptor.update(line) + decryptor.finalize()).decode("UTF-8")
    line = (line.split("-~-"))[1]
    print(line)
```

For better illustration the data in entry.txt in decrypted state is mentioned below

> 1-~-{'location': '1', 'weather': '1', 'time': '00:58', 'data': '1'}-~-##########################
>
> 2-~-{'location': '2', 'data': '2', 'time': '00:58', 'weather': '2'}-~-##########################

Thanks in advance

**PS: Can't attach encrypted data because it is in binary format**

Answer (score 0):

After updating the padder from 128 to 256bit, my code was working:

```
padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()  # wasn't working

padder = padding.PKCS7(256).padder()  # working
```

I noticed that you imported padding, but didn't share the code, so I assumed you were using the [padding example from here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/padding/) for AES CBC using HMAC(all the "Context was already finalized." related errors are coming from the [HMAC module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac/)), and the [encryptor from here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#module-cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes).

I also got the same error at the following line, when adding the example cleartext:

```
padded_data = padder.update(b"{'location': '2', 'data': '2', 'time': '00:58', 'weather': '2'}")

cryptography.exceptions.AlreadyFinalized: Context was already finalized.
```

I didn't test the reading from file part, but assuming it's running into the same problems.

[Padding doesn't add security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29999/224871) and you might be better off using different modes.

p.s.1 The key is 32 bytes long, and iv is 16 bytes long.

p.s.2 Hope you read the description of the hazmat module :)

*This is a “Hazardous Materials” module. You should ONLY use it if you’re 100% absolutely sure that you know what you’re doing because this module is full of land mines, dragons, and dinosaurs with laser guns.*